# How to configure Angular2 build process in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I have created new app like this: `dotnet new angular`. Then, started it. Everything work fine.

Then I added package `"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1"` and everything from [this](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/) article. Launched: everything ok, I can see map.

But if I stop project, then launch it again with no changes made - I have error with `Type parse`. Looks like it stops to do something with packages.

I started once again. Everything work fine at first start, but just after page reloaded - error.

Here's an error

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'latitude' since it isn't a known property of 'agm-map'.
1. If 'agm-map' is an Angular component and it has 'latitude' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'agm-map' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
<hr />
<agm-map [ERROR ->][latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@5:21
Can't bind to 'longitude' since it isn't a known property of 'agm-map'.
1. If 'agm-map' is an Angular component and it has 'longitude' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'agm-map' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
<hr />
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [ERROR ->][longitude]="lng">
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@5:38
```

What should I do to setup build process and get it work?

Comment: Please share code of your `@NgModule`

Comment: Did you import `AgmCoreModule` in both modules? server and client